# Observing Notification in Today Widget which is posted from main app

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, today-extension, notificationcenter

I have declared notification name in a swift file which has target membership of both main app and today widget:

```
let SpecialKey = Notification.Name("howLongNotif")
```

Then in my main app view controller, I am posting notification when location is updated (background mode for location updates is on):

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SpecialKey, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

In my today widget viewDidLoad, I am observing it like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TodayViewController.dataReceived), name: SpecialKey, object: nil)
```

and have:

```
func dataReceived(_notification: NSNotification) {
    print("data received")
}
```

But `dataReceived` function is never invoked.

I tested by moving the observer and dataReceived function to main app and it works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main app and today is extension are run as separate processes on the phone. `NSNotificationCenter` only works within a single process.

To pass information between your extension and main app, you can use `NSUserDefaults` or a file in the shared container.

Comment: problem with NSUserDefaults is that to get live information, I will need to keep writing and reading from them, which does not sound like a good solution for live info.

Comment: There's no good mechanism for that kind of live information. There's a good chance your main app isn't even running when your today extension is in use. What kind of live info are you wanting to communicate?

Comment: my main app runs in background mode and continuously (every second) communicates the location to today widget.

Comment: That use case isn't supported for today widgets. Even with your main app, updating the current location every second in the background will be very hard on the user's battery and doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: If you want more real-time communication, you can use the NSFileCoordination API as described here: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions, but I think you may want to rethink how your app currently works.