# Is it possible to find application status from TODAY EXTENSION

Tags: ios, today-extension

Is it possible to know the host application status from the today extension? I know I can check the application status using `UIApplication.shared.applicationState` from the host app. But I want to know the host app status from the today extension.

Comment: I dont know a direct way to do this. However, this is possible via an "hacky" way. Today extension and main app can share informations via `UserDefaults` if they are in the same "app group". You could just write the status of your main app in your `UserDefaults` everytime it changes, and retrieve it in your today widget. source: https://jaanus.com/nsuserdefaults-default-values-and-app-extensions/

Comment: @Olympiloutre Thanks for your response. Already I'm using `UserDefaults` to share some other details. Is it possible to send Notification from host to extension once login or logout is performed in hot app. So that I can know when to check `UserDefaults` again.

Comment: @Olympiloutre It seems [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986695/observing-notification-in-today-widget-which-is-posted-from-main-app)

Comment: Even with a timer?

Comment: @Olympiloutre It seems thats the only option

Comment: Well at least it is feasible to communicate between the two. I dont know if it is possible to use KVO to detect UserDefaults changes. That would prevent using a Timer